# Files created by a Tomcat webapp and owner, owner group, permissions for this file

Tags: file, tomcat, file-permissions, file-ownership

-- Files created by a Tomcat webapp and owner, owner group, permissions for this file --

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

I am running a "Tomcat v6.0" webapp on a "Debian 7.2 Wheezy" OS.

In particular, this webapp creates some files on the filesystem.

The files created have:

- "tomcat6" as the owner user,
- "tomcat6" as the owner group,
- 644 as the permissions granted to the owner, the owner group and others respectively.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

What I like to do is:

- set the owner user to "user1",
- set the owner group to "group1",
- set the permissions to 660
  for every new file created.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use `umask` for permissions. For ownership, you'll have to change the effective uid and gid of the process to do that. If you want, you could write a cron job that changes file ownership periodically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was more looking for a solution which would have involved the creation of ACLs (Access Control Lists)...
A rule/rules associated to a directory that would force the owner, owner group and permissions of new files and directories...